# Xamarin iOS Splash Screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.4).

I've been following this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=windows

Which is fairly straightforward.  My splash screen is simply a blue background with my logo in the centre.  However, I cannot work out how to centralise the logo on every iOS device and both portrait and landscape.

Do I have to create a different Asset or LaunchScreen.storyboard for every device?

[image]

Comment: What I have found is someone spent a great deal of time creating this experience and it's utterly confusing garbage, unfortunately. I've spent an hour tweaking every possible property and not getting any different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I am familiar with that you can create a responsive design in iOS is to use the concept of [AutoLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout).

But before you start that you should be aware of the [basics of designing in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/introduction?tabs=macos)

Goodluck

Feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: Still having issues.  It's centred on the device I specify in the designer (eg iPhone), but when I choose to run it on an iPad, the image is top left.  As though the coordinates are absolute.  I added my test image to the question.

Comment: Do you have a bare minimum example project I could compare to mine?

Comment: I've found more options and managed to centre it on the X-Axis.  I think I need to add another constraint to centre it on the Y-Axis, but cannot see how.

Comment: Wait let me see if i can find anything!

Comment: I've got it working.  It's wasn't obvious, there were other menus (almost hidden).  I just kept playing around with the options until it worked.  But thanks for your help.

Comment: Pleasure, feel free to get back if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot work out how to centralise the logo on every iOS device and both portrait and landscape.

In the designer you can grab the dot in the centre of the view and then drag it to the vertical or horizontal lines:

[image]

[image]

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout#center-constraints

Comment: choose `Constraint Editing Mode` in storyboard.